Find the Galois group $G= Gal(L/K)$ where $L= \mathbb{R}(x,y)$ and $K=\mathbb{R}(x^2,y^2)$
Find the Galois group  $G= Gal(L/K)$   where $L= \mathbb{R}(x,y)$  and  $K=\mathbb{R}(x^2,y^2)$
My attempt :The minimial polynomial $f(a)$ is  $(a^2-x^2)(a^2-y^2)$
$f(a)=(a^2-x^2)(a^2-y^2) \in \mathbb{R}(x^2,y^2)(a)=K(a)$
The polynomial $f(a)$ has a degree of $4$
$|Gal(L/K)|=|Aut(L/K)|=4 \implies \mathbb{Z}_4 $  or $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$
I think $Gal(L/K)=\mathbb{Z}_4$

Try to determine some elements of the Galois group.

This is very confused. One speaks of the minimal polynomial of an element, not a pair of elements. You've chosen the strange name $a$ for the polynomial variable, and so the minimal polynomial of $x$ will be $a^2-x^2\in \mathbb{R}(x,y)[a]$ (not in $K$ as you assert.

@ancientmathematician Yes, you are right.

@ancientmathematician i edited

But surely you know that the polynomial ring is $K[a]$ not $K(a)$.

And you still have the irrelevant polynomial $(a^2-x^2)(a^2-y^2)$.

@ancientmathematician don't be so harsh. It's not wrong to say $f\in K(a)$, and $f$ is the minimal polynomial that generates $L/K$. It's not common to call $f$ a minimal polynomial, but that doesn't mean it's irrelevant.

Judging from your latest questions you may be a bit out of your depth. Here you could think of this extension as being of the type you get by adjoining two square roots - quite like $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)/\Bbb{Q}$. True, this example wanders away from the realm of number fields, the usual playground of first examples in Galois theory. Here the algebra is actually made a bit simpler due to algebraic independence of $x$ and $y$, saving you from the counterpart of having to prove that $\sqrt3\notin\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$.

Here is how I would tackle this question.
Let $L=\mathbb{R}(x,y)$, and let $K=\mathbb{R}(x^2,y^2)$.
That is $L$ is the field of rational functions in $x,y$ and $K$ is the subfield of those elements of $L$ which are functions of $x^2,y^2$. To avoid doubt: it is intended that $x,y$ are algebraically independent, in the sense that the only polynomial in $x,y$ which is zero is the zero polynomial.
Now consider the polynomial $f(X)\in K[X]$ given by $f(X):=(X^2-x^2)(X^2-y^2)$. It is clear that $f$ splits completely into linear factors in $L[X]$, as $f(X)=(X-x)(X+x)(X-y)(X+y)$. As $L=K[x,y]$ it is clear no smaller extension of $K$ splits $f$, and so $L$ is the splitting field of $f$ over $K$. Hence $L$ has a Galois Group over $K$, call it $G$.
How big is $|L:K|$?
Well we have that $L=K(x)(y)$, and so $|L:K|=|L:K(x)||K(x):K|$. Now $|L:K(x)|=|K(x)(y):K(x)|\leqslant |K(y):K|$. So we have that $|L:K|\leqslant|K(y):K||K(x):K|$. Now notice that $x$ satisfies $m_x(X)=X^2-x^2\in K[X]$; as neither of $(X\pm x)$ has coefficients in $K$ we see that $m_x$ is the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $K$, and hence $|K(x):K|=2$.
That is $|L:K|\leqslant 4$.
We now wish to find the $K$-automorphisms of $L$. Note that each of these is determined by its effects on $x,y$; and since $x$ must map to one of the roots of $m_x$ we see that there are at most $4$ automorphisms, given by $\sigma_0:(x,y)\mapsto (x,y)$, $\sigma_1:(x,y)\mapsto (-x,y)$, $\sigma_2:(x,y)\mapsto (x,-y)$, $\sigma_3:(x,y)\mapsto (-x,-y)$. As $x,y$ are algebraically independent always get a homomorphism when we substitute any $(\phi(x,y),\psi(x,y))$ for $(x,y)$; but the ones we have specified are clearly onto, so are automorphisms. Moreover, as they do different things to $(x,y)$ they are all different, so that the order of the Galois group $G$ is at least $4$.
Putting this together we have that $|L:K|=|G|=4$. Moreover $G=\{\sigma_0,\sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3\}$, and as each $\sigma$ squares to the identity we have that $G\simeq C_2\times C_2$.
